Can the optimal stopping problem be expressed in another form by strong Markov property?
$X_t$ is a strong Markov process in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$. $\tau$ is a stopping time, $T>0, \mathbb{E}_x(\cdot)=\mathbb{E}(\cdot|X_0=x)$. By Markov property, $\mathop{\rm{ess \sup}}\limits_{t \leqslant \tau \leqslant T}\mathbb{E}(X_{\tau}|\mathcal{F}_t)=\mathop{\rm{ess \sup}}\limits_{0 \leqslant \tau \leqslant T-t}\mathbb{E}_{X_t}(X_{\tau})$. Assume $v(t,x)=\sup\limits_{0\leqslant \tau \leqslant T-t}\mathbb{E}_{x}(X_\tau)$. My question is whether $v(t,X_t)=\mathop{\rm{ess \sup}}\limits_{0 \leqslant \tau \leqslant T-t}\mathbb{E}_{X_t}(X_{\tau})$ or not. Can it be obtained by strong Markov property?
